# Spatial Transformer Networks and Data Augmentation

Tags: neural-network, data, image-classification, computer-vision, data-augmentation

We are all familiar with the famous Deep Mind paper [STN](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.02025.pdf).

Upon implementation, such as [here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/spatial_transformer_tutorial.html), **did anyone still use input data augementation such as affine transformations**?

There are used to make CNN robust to rotation, transformation etc. I wonder how these/lack of these affect the output of STNs.